# Count and divide in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to display number of contacts per month.

I have the below query which is giving me incorrect results.

```
SELECT 
    a.DATE_YYYYMM,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL, COUNT(a.id)) / COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) Average_contacts_per_member_per_month,
    COUNT(a.id) Count_Total_Contacts_Per_Month,
    a.id
--INTO #temp_Contacts
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         *, 
         ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), l.SERVICE_DATE, 112),'') AS SERVICE_DATE_YYYYMM 
     FROM  l) a
WHERE 
    1=1 
    AND a.IS_V = 1  
GROUP BY 
    id, a.DATE_YYYYMM
```

My results for average and counts are the same and I know they should differ.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but if you could do any math outside of the query, it would help.\

Comment: Depending on the version of SQL you're using, I'd have thought that your calculation was going to drop fractions because the division of an int by an int will return an int.  If that happens convert the count(distinct) to decimal so that you get decimal division.

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by `a.id`, so the count is always going to be 1.

You want something more like:

```
SELECT a.DATE_YYYYMM,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL, COUNT(a.id))/COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) as Average_contacts_per_member_per_month,
       COUNT(a.id) as Count_Total_Contacts_Per_Month
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT *, 
             COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), l.SERVICE_DATE, 112), '') AS SERVICE_DATE_YYYYMM
      FROM [MCS].[JXM1563].[LTIH_SSIS] l  
     ) a
WHERE a.IS_V = 1 
GROUP BY a.DATE_YYYYMM
```